# How do I configure a Keystep to sound like a piano in FL Studio?

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard

I bought an Arturia Keystep which didnt come with an user manual or anything, only one page of a "Quick Start". Reading in internet I found that I can make it work with FL Studio, but when I connect it, by default it makes percussion sounds. I want it to sound similar to a piano or a synthesizer, ideally to sound like this [Levels cover](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bU-ZAQZznQs) which is used by someone who is using FL Studio apparently, judging by the description of the video.

How do I configure a Keystep to sound like a piano or a synthesizer in FL Studio?

Comment: The manuals for all Arturia products, including the different versions of the Keystep, can be found here: https://www.arturia.com/support/downloads&manuals The online manual for FL Studio can be found here: https://www.image-line.com/fl-studio-learning/fl-studio-online-manual/

Comment: I've found it very useful to find the instructions online, then print them off, for any new toy I get. That way, I can  write my own side note as I find out all the things it can (and can't) do.